# Require result with of multiple customers along with city name

Tags: postgresql

we have following requirement

I need customer_name which are in Active status and attribute_name=City and attribute_value in(Indore,Mumbai) and result should return count less than=2

**It means from result for Indore i should get 2 results out of 3 and for Mumbai i should get 1 out of 1.**

I tried below 2 ways but getting all the rows for customers which are in city Indore and Mumbai

**Customer_table** has below details

```
customer_id customer_name customer_Status
------------------------------------------
1           ABC            Active
2           XYZ            Active
3           PQR            NA
4           ABCD           Active
4           ABCDE          Active
```

**customer_details** table has below details

```
customer_id  attribute_name attribute_value
------------------------------------------
1            City            Indore
1            Phone Number    9100000000
1            Country         India
2            City            Mumbai
2            Phone Number    9100000001
2            Country         India
3            City            Delhi
3            Phone Number    9100000002
3            Country         India
4            City            Mumbai
4            Phone Number    9100000003
4            Country         India
5            City            Mumbai
5            Phone Number    9100000004
5            Country         India
```

### Code:-

```
select  attribute_value, r.customer_name from customer_details res
join lateral (
    select customer_name from Customer_table 
    where res.customer_id=customer_id     
    and customer_Status= 'Active'
    limit 2
) r on true
where attribute_name= 'City' and attribute_value in ('Indore','Mumbai');
```

### Code:-

```
SELECT s.customer_name,attribute_value
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ) AS rn
   FROM   customer_details
   WHERE   attribute_name= 'City' and attribute_value in ('Indore','Mumbai')
) e
JOIN   Customer_table s USING (customer_id)
WHERE  rn <= 2
and and customer_Status= 'Active'
ORDER  BY customer_id, e.rn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way.

```
select customer_name,attribute_value from (
select ct.customer_name,attribute_value,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute_value ) AS rn
from customer_table ct ,customer_details cd
where ct.customer_status = 'Active' and ct.customer_id = cd.customer_id
and attribute_name='City' and attribute_value in('Indore','Mumbai')
) as t
where rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This design will kill any performance you hope to get around customers. The first thing I would do in drop the customer_details table and the columns phone_number, city, and country to the customers table. Lacking that I would create a view that joined customers to customer_details having all the columns in the view.

```
create view Customer_Standard as 
    select c.cust_id, c.name, c.status, ph.attribute_value phone_number, ct.attribute_value city, cn.attribute_value country
      from customers c
      left join  customer_details ph on (ph.cust_id = c.cust_id and ph.attribute_name = 'Phone Number')
      left join  customer_details ct on (ct.cust_id = c.cust_id and ct.attribute_name = 'City')
      left join  customer_details cn on (cn.cust_id = c.cust_id and cn.attribute_name = 'Country') ;
```

Then the query you want becomes:

```
select cust_id, name, status, phone_number, city, country
  from (select cs.*, row_number() over (partition by city order by cust_id) rn
          from Customer_Standard cs
       ) cust
 where city in ('Indore','Mumbai')
   and rn<3;
```